# ConverterParameter: Setting it inside an ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, converters, itemtemplate

I'm trying to set the converter parameter to a property of an item inside an ItemTemplate.
Since ConverterParameter is not a dependency property Binding doesn't work.
But I don't really need a binding, just setting it once would be enough since it never changes.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="ItemsWithTypeProperty">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding SelectedItem.Base.Type, Converter={l:IsEqualConverter}, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter={Type}}" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

IsEqualConverter:
Convert: compares the value to the parameter and returns the result
ConvertBack: If the value is true it returns the parameter

The DataContext of the ItemTemplate is a class which contains the Property with the name "Type".
Its type is object.

Is there a way to replace {Type} with something that would just set it to (DataContext.)Type once? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly Type is. Is it the System.Type of the object? Is it always a fixed type? You could write something like:

```
ConverterParameter={x:Type local:TypeToCompare}
```

If Type isn't a constant, you could re-write your converter to implement IMultiValueConverter and use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613634.aspx).

Comment: No Type is not constant. Type in this case means the Property with the name "Type" of the DataContext object.  Multibinding was also my first thought but the problem with that is that I cannot convert it back. ConvertBack only supplies a bool value and it is not enough to convert it back to the object I need.

Comment: OK well in that case I would say either back to the drawing boards or if you really have to, you there are hacks to make ConverterParameter bindable. See http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/08/03/my-wish-came-true-i-can-now-use-databinding-in-a-converterparameter/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

```
......, ConverterParameter=Type}" />
```

And on your Converter :

```
    if ((string)parameter == "Type"))
    {
        //Do some stuff
    }
```

Comment: Type in this case is should be the value of the property Type of the Datacontext object.